# Wine: Unable to install a function driver for device L"WINEKEYBOARD"

Tags: arch-linux, wine

I currently have a problem with wine.
I'm using Archlinux and i have Wine in Version `6.9` installed.

If i run for example `winecfg` from the Terminal it gave me the following Error Message:

```
008c:err:plugplay:enumerate_new_device Unable to install a function driver for device L"WINEKEYBOARD\\vid_0000&pid_0000\\0&WINEKEYBOARD&0&1".
0064:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
0064:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Unknown error (998).
0064:err:systray:initialize_systray Could not create tray window
```

For me it seems like the first error about the `enumerate_new_device` causes the problems. But i don't know how to solve this error.

I also get the same error if i try to start my already installed Programs in `PlayOnLinux`

**Update**
If i try to create a new Wine Prefix (i have deleted the `.wine` folder and run `wine some.exe`) i get the following Messages:

```
wine: created the configuration directory '/home/user/.wine'
0048:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
0048:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Unknown error (998).
0048:err:systray:initialize_systray Could not create tray window
0048:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hr 0x80004002
0048:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, hr 0x80004002
0048:err:ole:apartment_get_local_server_stream Failed: 0x80004002
```

Comment: Just upgraded wine to wine-staging 6.12 (from 6.0 staging) and encountered this. Are you on staging, or something else?

Comment: P.S.: I don't think it's a fatal error, looks like they just added a keyboard stub device partially into wine in April. https://source.winehq.org/patches/data/204475 - I think your problem may be elsewhere, since I can still use `winecfg` just fine even with the message. If using X, check that your $DISPLAY variable's set; it looks like it can't find your X server to create a window on. If wayland, I have no idea; I never use wayland.

Comment: Same problem. Neither wine, nor winecfg start. wine-6.16 (Staging)